# How to set role permissions in WSO2 using admin webservices (setRoleUIPermission)

Tags: wso2

I have found the WSO2 carbon admin service that can be used to add role permissions using admin webservices (setRoleUIPermission). Based on the WSDL I have no clue how it should be used.

This is the request SoapUI generates:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mgt="http://mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <mgt:setRoleUIPermission>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mgt:roleName>?</mgt:roleName>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <mgt:rawResources>?</mgt:rawResources>
        </mgt:setRoleUIPermission>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How should rawResource be used?

Regards, nidkil

Answer (score 0):

First i guess,  it is great, if you can try out the method "getRolePermissions" in the API.  This method returns all UI permission (management console related permissions) mentioning that whether role contains permission or not.  Then you can see each permission has been identified by a resource value such as "/permission/admin/manage/modify/webapp". Therefore echo permission check box that is show under role permission UI,  has some hidden String value. That is value that you need to pass as "rawResources" in this method.  Ex if you want to give "login" permission to role "test". You need to pass like that.

AFAIK, these permissions that are return and can be set... is management console permissions that can be used in Carbon Admin services and in UI

```
         <xsd:roleName>test</xsd:roleName>
     <xsd:rawResources>/permission/admin/login</xsd:rawResources>
```

Comment: Hi Asela. Thx for the quick response. It works. How do I remove a permission?

Comment: I guess there is no method to remove permission in UserAdmin service. 1st you can "getRolePermissions" and then modified permission (add new ones or remove old ones) must be sent using "setRoleUIPermission" method

Comment: Hi Asela, I have tried both setRolUIPermissions and setRolPermissions and I am only able to get the "selected" element to change to "true" (permission granted). It never changes back to "false" (permission not granted). Any suggestions? By the way, what is the difference between setRolUIPermissions and setRolPermissions?